# How do I see if an established socket is stuck on a server that's expecting input?

Tags: php, sockets

I have a script that scans ports for open proxy servers.  Problem is if it encounters a login program (specifically telnet) then it hangs there forever since it doesn't know what to do and eventually the server closes the connection.

The simple solution would be to create a bunch of cases.  If telnet, do this.  If SSH, do that.  If something else, blah blah blah.  I'd like an umbrella solution since the script is not a high priority for me.

The script, as it is now, is available at http://parkrrr.net/socks/scan.phps

On a small scale (the page maybe averages 15 hits/day) it's fine but on a larger scale I'd be worried about a lot of open zombie sockets.

Swapping the !$strpos doesn't work since servers can return more information than what you requested (headers, ads, etc).

Only accepting a fixed number of bytes (as opposed to appending until EOF, which it does now) from the $fgets also does not seem to work.  I am sure this is where it gets stuck:
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $data.=fgets($fp,512);
    }

But what can I do?  Any other suggestions/warnings would also be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [non-blocking sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php) and [`stream_select`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) with a timeout or a strait poll.

Answer (score 1):

Use [stream_set_timeout](http://php.net/stream_set_timeout) to set a read/write timeout on the socket.